# Regular Expression for evaluating string which do not contains both substring 'ab' and 'cd' in order

Tags: regex

I want to build a regex for evaluating a string which does not contains both 2 substrings in ordering "ab" and "cd"

**Example:**

```
"This is ab test for cd" <= Not matched because containing "ab", "cd" in order
"This is cd test for ab" <= Matched because containing "ab" and "cd" but not in order
"This is cd test" <= Matched because not containing ab
"This is ab test" <= Matched because not containing cd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
^(?!.*\sab\s.*?\scd\b).*
```

OR

```
^(?!.*\bab\b.*?\bcd\b).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zB9kA3/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!.*?\bab\b.*?\bcd\b)(?!.*?\bcd\b.*?\bab\b).*$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/30